# Laravel 5 - link to named route with parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to use REST-ful routing with Laravel 5.1.19, but I cannot generate a link to a named route and inject its parameters.
Here's my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::resource('page', '\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Page');
```

The output from `php artisan route:list`:

```
    +--------+----------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
    | Domain | Method   | URI                          | Name                 | Action                                                        | Middleware |
    +--------+----------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
    |        | GET|HEAD | /                            |                      | Closure                                                       |            |
    |        | GET|HEAD | _debugbar/assets/javascript  | debugbar.assets.js   | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\AssetController@js              |            |
    |        | GET|HEAD | _debugbar/assets/stylesheets | debugbar.assets.css  | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\AssetController@css             |            |
    |        | GET|HEAD | _debugbar/clockwork/{id}     | debugbar.clockwork   | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\OpenHandlerController@clockwork |            |
    |        | GET|HEAD | _debugbar/open               | debugbar.openhandler | Barryvdh\Debugbar\Controllers\OpenHandlerController@handle    |            |
    |        | GET|HEAD | admin                        |                      | Closure                                                       |            |
    |        | POST     | page                         | page.store           | \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Page@store                        |            |
    |        | GET|HEAD | page                         | page.index           | \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Page@index                        |            |
    |        | GET|HEAD | page/create                  | page.create          | \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Page@create                       |            |
    |        | PATCH    | page/{page}                  |                      | \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Page@update                       |            |
    |        | PUT      | page/{page}                  | page.update          | \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Page@update                       |            |
    |        | DELETE   | page/{page}                  | page.destroy         | \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Page@destroy                      |            |
    |        | GET|HEAD | page/{page}                  | page.show            | \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Page@show                         |            |
    |        | GET|HEAD | page/{page}/edit             | page.edit            | \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Page@edit                         |            |
    +--------+----------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

So my understanding is that if I want to link to the Edit method for a Page with ID = 1, I'd have to do this:

`<a href="{!! route('page.edit', ['page' => $page->id]) !!}">{{$page->title}}</a>`

However, when I put this in a blade template, it produces the following string:
`http://localhost:8181/page//edit` (notice the missing parameter between 'page' and 'edit')
According to Artisan's output I should supply a 'page' parameter, which I am, but it's not picking it up. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `dd(route('page.edit',['page' => 1]));` and see what happens.

Comment: Welp, I guess it's time to take a break... Turns out my "pages" table does not have a column named "id", so it just kind of skips it. I'm sorry for wasting everybody's time... PS: I'm still new to L5, in L4 this would've thrown an Exception.

Comment: i try to find way to user named routes in links - thanks to your post I found answer -thanks +1 :)